# how to get variables fill the ram in android

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

How can I check which **variables** of my `Android App` are already in **RAM** and fill it?

Task manager just show how much ram used by the whole app.

Comment: All of your program's variables allocated in RAM

Comment: my android application give about 80mb of ram space. i want to find out which variable fill this space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Memory allocation tracker](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html) tool.