# How could I get the current time of the currently played video? from VLC Player for Android

Tags: android, video, vlc, vlc-android

Let's say I'm playing a video on VLC player for Android [*[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UuMx.png)*].
And at any point while watching it I could trigger a script that should get the value of the current time [[*Img*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDQfI.png)] to append it to a text file. How could I get the current time of the currently played video at the time at which I triggered the script?

Note: I need to develop a separate tool from VLC player (not embedded within it) so the method of getting the current time value should consider this.

---

**My thoughts trying to get to a solution:**

- Thought 1:
  I'm not sure if [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) or [Automagic](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.gridvision.ppam.androidautomagic&hl=en) can trigger some script to get the current time value.
- Thought 2: There's a tool that can read values stored by third-party applications directly from memory called [Cheat Engine](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-cheat-and-hack-flash-based-games/) for Desktops, [recommended by Ascorbin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21332942/3503851). I'm not sure if we can use something similar for Android to get the current time value directly from memory.

Comment: Unless the VLC app has an API for this, I doubt that it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

As CommonsWare [was suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39987201/how-could-i-get-the-current-time-of-the-currently-played-video-from-vlc-player#comment67253290_39987201), without an API it is going to be very tricky to get that info.

So maybe one option is to use the [VLC SDK (libVLC)](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC/#libVLC_on_Android) to develop a lightweight player that uses VLC's engine, while keeping the feature you want to get?